# Extracting rows from a cell vector

Tags: matlab, row, cell

This is a really simple question, but I can't believe how stuck I am.

I have a file where each column is a different format. Some are string, some are int.
By using textscan I can get the file into MATLAB as a vector of cells.

What I want to do is create a new matrix where only cats under age 10 are in.

```
Animal Age
Cat 11
Dog 5
Cat 2
Dog 11
Cat 16
Cat 3
```

This wouldn't be a problem if it wasn't for the fact that they're in their individual cells. A{1} gives me a list of animals, A{2} gives me a list of ages. If it can be solved by not using textscan that's an option as well, as the way to read the file doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how i would do it

```
 FileId2=fopen('Animals.txt')
 title=textscan(FileId2,'%s %s',1);   % this reads only the first line 
 data==textscan(FileId2,'%s %d');     % reads the rest of the file and stores them in string and in
 Cat=strcmp(D{1},'Cat');              % looks for Animal of type cat
 Age=data{2};                         % gets the age of the animal
 Ageofcats=Age(Cat);                  % get the age of cats 
 % and then you just find what you want
 find(Ageofcats<10);
```